# android:allowTaskReparenting does not work on Android 5

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

The attribute `android:allowTaskReparenting` defined in `<activity>` decides
whether or not the activity can move from the task that started it to the task it has an affinity for when that task is next brought to the front — "true" if it can move, and "false" if it must remain with the task where it started.

It seems that this attribute does not work properly on Android 5. In my test case for example, Task 1 contains activity A and activity B, where activity B is an activity from another app say App-2, and the `android:allowTaskReparenting` is set to "true". On Android 4.4 and previous versions, if now I launch App-2, activity B would be replaced from Task 1 to the top of App-2's back stack since activity B has the same affinity with App-2. However, this documented behavior does not happen on Android 5. Activity B remains in task 1 just like `android:allowTaskReparenting="true"` is not set at all.

Does anyone notice this and know what changes in the newest Android version? Many thanks in advance.